# BLE/NRF52 - Connect two BLE-Centrals (Smartphone) with one Peripheral but receive the same notify signal?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, nrf52

I am planning to develop a small project with a NRF52 (or other BLE chip if that'd matter). Preliminary, I would like to know, if I can broadcast data without "abusing" the advertising bytes?

Scenario: Two smartphones connect with my device and they enable some notify-characteristic over which i would like to receive data with a potentially high frequency (up to 100Hz maybe) on both devices. (I know 100Hz is already close to the minimum 7,5ms or so that ble supports... just to say i wanna reach that limit basically and be as fast as possible with receiving)

So: if I connect two central devices, will they receive the same notify signal or will I have to send one for each central device, essentially lowering the max frequency at which i can receive data?

In the latter case, is the best way to broadcast ble data to multiple devices via the advertising bytes?

Kind regards, have a good one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use GATT notifications over BLE, the notifications are individual per connection. So if you want to send the same notification to two connected clients, the data is duplicated over the air. In general, all GATT traffic is individual per connection.

If you send one packet per 10 ms to two devices, that should be fine. Note though if one packet is lost, it will be resent during the next connection event and hence then two packes will be sent to that device (assuming you produce an additional packet after 10 ms as usual).

You can use advertising instead to broadcast data. Every device that scans can see your data. Data you send in ADV_IND can be seen by an unlimited amount of scanners.

If it's better to use advertisements or GATT to send data to multiple devices depends on a lot of factors. You should experiment what works best for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, then advertising is probably my way to go :)

BTW i read that notification differs to "indication" in a way that for notification there's no acknowledge, meaning that if one packet is lost... it's just lost i'd say. But that contradicts your second paragraph

Comment: BLE uses a reliable transport over the air. Every packet is resent until acknowledged by the remote link layer. The only way a notification is allowed to be dropped is when the receiver's Bluetooth stack receives a notification, but would run out of memory because the application is not consuming the previous notifications fast enough. This can't happen with indications because there can be at most one outstanding indication.